# Javascript Prototyping: Using multiple names for the same class

Tags: javascript

```
function test(){
}

test.prototype.doSomething = function () {  
return true;
}
```

in this example I can access test.doSomething(); But it whould be cool to just type t.doSomething();
Is it possible to define something like an alias for my class test?

Answer (score 1):

Reference it in another variable. `test` will still exist. It's just that the variable `t` refers to it.

```
var t = test;
test.doSomething(); //test does something
t.doSomething();    //t does the same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph's answer is spot on, but it's also worth nothing that your `test` function could be invoked as a [Constructor via the `new` keyword](http://pivotallabs.com/users/pjaros/blog/articles/1368-javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword):

```
var t = new test();
t.doSomething();
```